# Mongoose 5.2.1 Getting MongoDB connection error: MongoError: no mongos proxy available

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Any assistance on the following matter is appreciated. In researching the following extensively but not finding anything, there appears to be a problem with the NodeJS MongoDB driver or a change to mongoose causing the following error: "MongoError: no mongos proxy available"

As an example, when using the following module:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

//Setup with native ES6 Promise Library
mongoose.Promise = Promise;

//Setup UUID type i.e. const { UUID } = mongoose.Types;
require("mongoose-uuid2")(mongoose);

//Extend mongoose object with uuid operations - uuid.v4 method i.e. mongoose.uuid.v4
const uuid = require("uuid/v4");

//Extend mongoose object - Setup bson type - i.e. mongoose.bson
const bson = require("bson");

//Extend mongoose object - Setup Url type i.e. - mongoose.SchemaTypes.Url
require("mongoose-type-url");

//Extend mongoose object - Setup extend_schema i.e. - mongoose.extend_schema();
const extend_schema = require("mongoose-extend-schema");

/*
 *Initializes new instance of mongoose, sets up instance, provides reference to instance
 *Wires up the models to the instance
 *Defaults to test database using uri string
 */
class MongooseSetupService {

  constructor(uri = "mongodb://localhost:27017/test", debug = false) {

    const db = mongoose.connection;

    mongoose.uuid = uuid;
    mongoose.bson = bson;
    mongoose.extend_schema = extend_schema;

    this._database_uri = uri;
    this._mongoose = mongoose;

    mongoose.connect(this._database_uri, { "useNewUrlParser": true });
    mongoose.set("debug", debug);
    MongooseSetupService.listen(db);
  }

  get mongoose () {
    return this._mongoose;
  }

  static listen(db) {
    db.on("error", (error) => {
      console.error(`MongoDB connection error: ${error}`);
    });

    db.on("open", () => {
      console.log("Connected to MongoDB");
    });

    db.on("connected", () => {
      console.log(`Mongoose default connection open to ${this._database_uri}`);
    });

    db.on("disconnected", () => {
      console.log("Mongoose default connection disconnected");
    });

    //If the Node process ends, close the Mongoose connection
    process.on("SIGINT", () => {
      db.close(() => {
        console.log("Mongoose default connection disconnected through app termination");
        process.exit(0);
      });
    });
  }
}

module.exports = MongooseSetupService;
```

If I attempt to consume it, such as in:

```
const MongoSetupService = require('./test2')

const mongo_setup_service = new MongoSetupService(
    'mongodb://user:password@server-1.domain.com:27017,server-2.domain.com:27017,server-3.domain.com:27017/db?ssl=true&replicaSet=rs0', true 
);
```

I get the following error message:

```
MongoError: no mongos proxy available
```

Here is the package.json dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "bson": "^3.0.0",
    "mongodb": "^3.1.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.2.1",
    "mongoose-extend-schema": "git+https://github.com/thxmike/mongoose-extend-schema.git",
    "mongoose-type-url": "^1.0.4",
    "mongoose-uuid2": "^2.1.0",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2"
  }
```

This recently started happening with the recent version of Mongoose (5.2.1)
It is using 3.1.1 of the NodeJS MongoDB driver. 
The debug log provides on the error message.
Any assistance in this matter is appreciated.

---

After some further investigation, it appears to be a problem with the option 
{ useNewUrlParser: true }. This was added due to a Warning message provided by the connection. 
If I remove this option, the problem goes away.
Also, if I remove &replicaSet=rs0 from the connection string uri, the problem comes back. Interesting how this driver is working with different settings. It would be nice if more information on these settings are provided.